# Parenting a mesh to a particle

Tags: mesh, particles, constraints, parent

I have made a character with particle hair. The hair is dynamic and it works fine. I want to attach beads to a strand, so that it moves along with the strand of hair. However, I can not find the right button to do this.
If this is possible, how can it be done?

Comment: if no button is available, try using python read particle position and assign  it to the bead

Comment: I tried to use AnimationNodes to get this effect, but the AN "particles from object" doesn't seem to have the correct information for hair particle systems.